# Are commas not always used in German?

Tags: punctuation, comma

I was going through one of the answers here and noticed this sentence:

> Bis auf Heinz habe ich alle angerufen.

Shouldn't it be

> Bis auf Heinz, habe ich alle angerufen.

Are commas often ignored in German?

Answer (score 16):

Zwischen einer vor dem Verb gestellten syntaktischen Gruppe und dem Verb liegt  kein Komma  vor:

> Um zehn Uhr kam er zurück.
>   Nach dem Regen wachsen die Pilze schnell.

Dies erklärt  dein Beispiel.

**Ausnahme**
Ein Komma ist notwendig wenn die syntaktische Gruppe durch ein Demonstrativ wieder aufgenommen  ist :

> Im Dom, da steht ein Bildnis
>   Auf goldenem Leder gemalt (Heine, *Lyrisches Intermezzo*)

**Translation of the above**
There is no comma between a syntactic group placed in front of a verb and that verb:

> Um zehn Uhr kam er zurück.
>   Nach dem Regen wachsen die Pilze schnell.

This explains your example.

**An exception**
A comma *is* necessary if the syntactic group is repeated through a demonstrative:

> Im Dom, da steht ein Bildnis
>   Auf goldenem Leder gemalt (Heine, *Lyrisches Intermezzo*)